# Kivy: understanding widget instances in apps

Tags: python, python-2.7, drawing, kivy

I'm still warming up to this Kivy stuff, hope you don't mind another question from me!

I'm trying to understand scheduled events for some of my widgets. For the sake of context, I want to be able to move nodes onto edges, and have the edges 'snap to' the node.

Here is my .kv file:

```
<GraphInterface>:
    node: graph_node
    edge: graph_edge

    GraphNode:
        id: graph_node
        center: self.parent.center

    GraphEdge:
        id: graph_edge
        center: 200,200

<GraphNode>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Color:
        rgba: (root.r,1,1,1)
    Ellipse:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size


<GraphEdge>:
    size: self.size
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: (root.r,1,1,1)
        Line:
            width: 2.0
            close: True
```

I have a collision detection event between nodes and edges, and I am dynamically creating nodes and edges within my program. Here is the relevant python code:

```
class GraphInterface(Widget):
    node = ObjectProperty(None)
    edge = ObjectProperty(None)

    def update(self, dt):
        # detect node collision
        self.edge.snap_to_node(self.node)
        return True

class GraphEdge(Widget):
    r = NumericProperty(1.0)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GraphEdge, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            self.line = Line(points=[100, 200, 200, 200], width = 2.0, close = True)

    def snap_to_node(self, node):
        if self.collide_widget(node):
            print "collision detected"
            del self.line.points[-2:]
            self.line.points+=node.center
            self.size = [math.sqrt(((self.line.points[0]-self.line.points[2])**2 + (self.line.points[1]-self.line.points[3])**2))]*2
            self.center = ((self.line.points[0]+self.line.points[2])/2,(self.line.points[1]+self.line.points[3])/2)
    pass

class GraphApp(App):

    def build(self):
        node = GraphNode()
        game = GraphInterface()

        createNodeButton = Button(text = 'CreateNode', pos=(100,0))
        createEdgeButton = Button(text = 'CreateEdge')
        game.add_widget(createNodeButton)
        game.add_widget(createEdgeButton)

        #scatter = Scatter(do_rotation=False, do_scale=False)
        #scatter.add_widget(node)

        def createNode(instance):
            newNode = GraphNode()
            game.add_widget(newNode)
            #scatter.add_widget(newNode)
            print "Node Created"

        def createEdge(instance):
            newEdge = GraphEdge()
            game.add_widget(newEdge)
            #scatter.add_widget(newEdge)
            print "Edge Created"

        createNodeButton.bind(on_press=createNode)
        createEdgeButton.bind(on_press=createEdge)

        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0/60.0)   
        return game
```

Ok, so that's a lot to read (sorry)!

Basically my collision is only detected for the initial edges and nodes I create in the .kv file. The newly created edges and nodes cannot interact via the collision mechanism.

I can put up more code if people want but I think that should be all the relevant parts. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

New method:

```
def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    if touch.grab_current is self:
        self.pos=[touch.x-25,touch.y-25]
    for widget in self.parent.children:
        if isinstance(widget, GraphEdge) and widget.collide_widget(self):
            print "collision detected"
            widget.snap_to_node(self)
            return True
    return super(GraphNode, self).on_touch_move(touch)
```

With this code I can still break the connection by moving the nodes quickly.

**EDIT2:**

I perhaps gave the answer a little prematurely. I can only interact with the first edge I spawned. And I also have a weird bug where the first edge and the first node seem to have the same color properties. Though perhaps this should be posed in it's own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't react to new `GraphEdge`s or `GraphNode`s being added to your `GraphInterface`. In `update`:

```
    self.edge.snap_to_node(self.node)
```

`self.edge` is always the kv-created `GraphEdge`. Same with `self.node`.

You should try adding this interaction to the `GraphNode` class itself, in your touch interactions. Try something like this in `GraphNode.on_touch_move()`:

```
for widget in self.parent.children:
    if isinstance(widget, GraphEdge) and widget.collide_widget(self):
        print "collision detected"
        ...
        break
```

This way, each `GraphNode` searches through its siblings for any `GraphEdge` with which it may collide.

Comment: Thanks again Ryan! I am seeing the same issue I had before with the nodes however. The edge doesn't snap to the node if I move too fast. I tried use a similar fix to before with no success. I will upload the updated method, perhaps I've done something obviously wrong :). Thanks again!

Comment: In your edit you say "break the connection" - does this mean that the edge snaps, but then you are able to pull the node away from the edge and not snap anymore? If you want the edge to stay connected, you should add specific functionality to do that and stop checking collision once the edge is attached to the node.

Comment: What you say is correct. I am sort of hacking this code together as I try to figure out how to do things. My end goal is an interactive graph network, and I am very far from that! I do not currently like how I update the node positions, I will try to think of a new to do this.
I also added a bit on the end about some coloring bug, is this something I can easily fix? (I'll make a new question if it is significant enough). Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure about that. You should probably just make a new question for this with some extra details and code/kv.

Comment: Ok, sure. I just feel like each change I make introduces a bunch of new issues I can't resolve (or find resolutions to online).

I'll post up a question for the color bug.

I still have the issue in this question that my nodes are only interacting with the first edge though. I have no idea how to implement the functionality you described above but I'm willing to give it a go :).