# Kivy: Widgets sharing unwanted properties

Tags: python, python-2.7, drawing, kivy

Related: [Kivy: understanding widget instances in apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317612/kivy-understanding-widget-instances-in-apps/)

I am initializing my app with 2 widget instances, the (.kv) file is as follows:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<GraphInterface>:
    node: graph_node
    edge: graph_edge

    GraphNode:
        id: graph_node
        center: self.parent.center

    GraphEdge:
        id: graph_edge
        center: 150,200


<GraphNode>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: (root.r,1,1,1)
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


<GraphEdge>:
    size: self.size
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: (root.r,1,1,1)
        Line:
            width: 2.0
            close: True
```

The node and edge objects are defined as follows:

```
class GraphNode(Widget):
    r = NumericProperty(1.0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.size= [50,50]
        self.pos = [175,125]
        self.r = 1.0
        super(GraphNode, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            if touch.grab_current == None:
                self.r = 0.6
                touch.grab(self)             
                return True                
        return super(GraphNode, self).on_touch_down(touch)


    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            self.pos=[touch.x-25,touch.y-25]
        for widget in self.parent.children:
            if isinstance(widget, GraphEdge) and widget.collide_widget(self):
                print "collision detected"
                widget.snap_to_node(self)
                return True
        return super(GraphNode, self).on_touch_move(touch)



    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            touch.ungrab(self)
            self.r = 1.0
            # and finish up here

    pass



class GraphEdge(Widget):
    r = NumericProperty(1.0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GraphEdge, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            self.line = Line(points=[100, 200, 200, 200], width = 2.0, close = True)


    def snap_to_node(self, node):
        if self.collide_widget(node):
            print "collision detected"
            del self.line.points[-2:]
            self.line.points+=node.center
            self.size = [math.sqrt(((self.line.points[0]-self.line.points[2])**2 + (self.line.points[1]-self.line.points[3])**2))]*2
            self.center = ((self.line.points[0]+self.line.points[2])/2,(self.line.points[1]+self.line.points[3])/2)
            return True
        pass
```

Sorry that there is so much code here, I don't know which part is causing the issue though I suspect it is simply the way I am initializing in the (.kv) file.

**Key Problem:**

When I click on the node the edge changes colour as well, despite the fact they do not share the same colour property. (I also tried renaming the GraphEdge colour property, but the issue still arises).

Below I show the issue, and the expected result (respectively).
[image: Image of Problem:]
[image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were actually trying to create two edges - one in `with self.canvas:` in your `GraphEdge` class (where you did not specified color) and second in your *.kv file (where you did not specified points). So you can remove whole `<GraphEdge>` in your *.kv file and then expand `with self.canvas:` like this:

```
with self.canvas:
    Color(self.r, 1, 1, 1)
    self.line = Line(points=[100, 200, 200, 200], width = 2.0, close = True)
```